# Complex object with List to List

Tags: automapper

i have two objects:

source:

```
public class ActualCostBatchCreateCommand : IRequest
{
   public List BatchList { get; }
   public string UserName { get; }

   public ActualCostBatchCreateCommand(List<ActualCostModel> batchList, string userName)
   {
      BatchList = batchList;
      UserName = userName;
   }
}
```

destination:

```
   public partial class ApprovalCost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateInvoice { get; set; }
    public string DateInvoiceFormat { get; set; }
    public decimal? LabHourlyRate { get; set; }
    public string LabHourlyRateCurrency { get; set; }
    public decimal? NumberOfHours { get; set; }
    public string ChargeType { get; set; }
    public decimal? TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

i have mapping config between ActualCostModel & ApprovalCost

```
CreateMap<ActualCostModel, Infrastructure.Database.ApprovalCost>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LabHourlyRateCurrency,
                expr => expr.MapFrom(src => src.LabHourlyRateCurrency.Key));

CreateMap<ActualCostBatchCreateCommand, ApprovalCost>().IncludeMembers(s=> s.BatchList)
```

and

the mapping:

```
var entities = _mapper.Map<List<ApprovalCost>>(ActualCostBatchCreateCommand);
```

when I validate configuration it throws a wired error that i need to add List to List mapping, according to the doc, I definitely don't need to do it, could you please help me figure out how the correct mapping config should look like?

Answer (score 0):

resolved by using

```
        public class ActualCostBatchCreateCommandListApprovalCostConverter : ITypeConverter<ActualCostBatchCreateCommand,List<ApprovalCost>>
        {
           public List<ApprovalCost> Convert(ActualCostBatchCreateCommand source, List<ApprovalCost> destination, ResolutionContext context)
           {
              return source.BatchList.Select(_ => context.Mapper.Map<ApprovalCost>(_)).ToList();
           }
        }
```

and

```
CreateMap<ActualCostBatchCreateCommand, List<ApprovalCost>>().ConvertUsing(new ActualCostBatchCreateCommandListApprovalCostConverter());
```